# Tuning Oracle SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle

I've got this large transaction database that I'm trying to pull data out of.  Basically one of the fields in the header table has a '0' in it, and each time I execute this stored procedure, I want to get n number of rows from the header that have a 0, but only those rows that meet some criteria, one of which is that a joined table (indexed, of course) has a matching value to a constant I designate.

Here is the query:

```
select /*+ FIRST_ROWS(1000)*/ T.ID        
    from HEADER T 
    JOIN (
          SELECT /*+ parallel(TC,4) FULL(TC) */ 
          tc.ID, tc.SOURCE_ID, tc.CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER FROM
          SUBTABLE tc, (SELECT ID, MAX(IDENT_SEQUENCE_ID) as IDENT_SEQUENCE_ID FROM SUBTABLE
          WHERE SOURCE_ID = 9002 AND upper(trim(CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER)) <> 'UNKNOWN'  GROUP BY ID) maxtc
          WHERE maxtc.ID = tc.ID AND
          maxtc.CUST_IDENT_SEQUENCE_ID = tc.CUST_IDENT_SEQUENCE_ID
        ) cust
        ON t.ID = cust.ID
        where T.batch=0 and T.status=6  and rownum <= SOME_NUMBER_HERE;
```

I was hoping the "FIRST_ROWS" or the rownum limit would make this basically just look for the first "SOME_NUMBER_HERE" number of records and return, but instead it seems Oracle is scanning the whole table?

Anyway to make it run faster, by stopping the select statement inside the join, after finding a certain number of matching rows?

I've got indexes on CUSTOMER_IDENTIFIER & SOURCE_ID on the SUBTABLE, and BATCH/STATUS on the HEADER.

This seems to run sub-second when I've got a hundred thousand rows, but takes several minutes when running on multi-millions rows...  Thanks in advance for any assistance...

Comment: What is the explain plan on this query and the indexes on the table?

Comment: Also, are cust_ident_sequence_id and ident_sequence_id meant to be the same thing? What is the primary key of subtable? ID and IDENT_SEQUENCE_ID??

Comment: Sorry, yes the IDENT_SEQUENCE_IDs are the same thing.

Comment: "it seems Oracle is scanning the whole table?" Why don't you take the uncertainty out and check the query plan? At least check the query plan with and without your hints and rownum operator and see if there is any difference. You can probably use windowing functions to replace your `cust` subtable much faster.